# Firebase Deleting a Row Not Firing the Firebase Listeners

Tags: ios, swift

I have a UITableView where I delete a row. I have configured the observers in my viewDidLoad function. When I delete a row inside commitEditingStyle the observers never gets fired.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    guard let currentUser = FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser else {
        return
    }

    let drivewaysRef = FIRDatabase.database().reference(withPath: "driveways")

    let queryRef = drivewaysRef.queryOrdered(byChild: "email").queryEqual(toValue: currentUser.email!)

    queryRef.observe(.value, with: { (snapshot) in

        for item in snapshot.children {
            let driveway = Driveway(snapshot: item as! FIRDataSnapshot)
            self.driveways.append(driveway)
        }

        self.tableView.reloadData()

    })

}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    if editingStyle == .delete {

        let driveway = self.driveways[indexPath.row]
        driveway.reference.removeValue()
    }

}
```

Comment: Is self.driveways an array of references? If thats the case, it looks like the observer is only added to the queryRef and not all the References in that array. I might be missing something here though..

Comment: Yeah I wanted to add an observer on a filtered query. I only want to fetch and observe the driveways that are posted by the particular user.

Comment: I would suggest trying to add the observer to the drivewaysRef instead of the queryRef. It looks like that is what will be deleted when you delete the cell. Replacing "queryRef.observe" with drivewaysRef.observe I believe should work.